# Where can I get this cursor on Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: mouse, cursor

I want to use this cursor in a my Qt application. However, I am unable to find the location of this cursor file on my Ubuntu desktop.

Any help regarding cursor location, web link to download this cursor etc. are appreciated.

Image of cursor I am looking for:

[image: hand pointing cursor image]

*Please this is the only reference image I am able to find while googling & only the hint I have.*